# NPM Mac OS error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gatsby

I'm trying to install gatsby-cli globally:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

I keep getting an access error and am not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to execute in super user mode(root user) like this

```
sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Answer (score 13):

Adding `sudo` is not the correct approach because when npm runs under sudo the files it will create will have ownership of root. Which you cannot access/readonly from your current non-su user.

Recommended way is to reinstall node and npm, Maybe when you installed node you installed as sudo. Or changing the Global folder for NPM.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

Another way would be to reclaim the `node_modules` folder. Just paste this below line in terminal this should work as-is.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

**Warning**: Pleas use exact path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Don't use `/usr/local/lib/` or something.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not administrator in your machine, you need to install global packages using `sudo`.

```sh
sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

change your file permissions .. like this

first check who owns the directory

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

it is denying access because the node_module folder is owned by root

drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel  102 Jun 24 23:24 node_modules

so this needs to be changed by changing root to your user but first run command below to check your current user How do I get the name of the active user via the command line in OS X?

```
id -un
```

OR

```
whoami
```

then change owner

```
sudo chown -R [owner]:[owner] /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

OR

```
sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

OR

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```